# Is this a correct use of Bayesian statistics when choosing a box A-E?

Tags: bayesian

Occasionally my friends and I attend a local pub quiz.

In the final round of the quiz, the winning team is allowed to select one box from five, labelled:
A, B, C, D, E

In one of these boxes is a £250 prize.
The others contain the following prizes:
£1, £10, £20, £50

Once a decision has been made, the contents of the other boxes will be revealed one by one (complete with drum roll for dramatic effect). This continues until there are only two boxes left on the screen: The one that definitely has £250, and the box they picked. **They are now given the opportunity to swap their box for the other box, and open that one instead.**

So let's say the team picked B. The first "reveal" has been done and now on the screen only boxes A and B are left. One definitely has the £250 in it. **The team can now either open B (their first choice), or swap and open A.**

At this point, a friend of mine (who has a university degree in mathematics) always says the following: *"Bayesian statistics says that they should swap boxes."*

I have no idea what "Bayesian statistics" is but, from a common-sense point of view, I see this as a straight 50-50 choice, and swapping should make no difference to one's chances of winning the top prize.

So my questions are:

**1) Is this a case where my friend should even be applying Bayesian statistics?**

**2) Does the Bayesian model say he is right that the team should swap their box at the end?**

Thanks in advance. This should help solve a rather acrimonious and pointless debate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the classic Monty Hall problem. You *can* show the solution with Bayesian inference, but it's not really necessary to come to the right conclusion, which is that you should definitely switch.

https://sc5.io/posts/how-to-solve-the-monty-hall-problem-using-bayesian-inference/#gref

Intuitively, you had a 1/5 chance of picking the right box to begin with. When the other boxes are opened specifically to avoid the prize, it hasn't changed your odds of having picked correctly to begin with - you still only have a 1/5 chance of having the prize in your box. Essentially, you can stick with your original choice, or switch to *choosing the other four boxes together, and taking the prize if it's in any of them*. You will win 20% of the time by sticking, and 80% of the time by switching.

Comment: Lovely, thanks! That's annoying that he's right, though... :)